# How to identify whether a linux VM is running on hyper-v environment?

Tags: hyper-v

I want to know if the linux VM is running on Hyper-V environment. Is there any way I can identify? Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

It can be determined by installing `virt-what`

here is documentation
https://linux.die.net/man/1/virt-what

as an example, install on ubuntu:

```
sudo apt install virt-what
```

usage:

```
sudo virt-what
```